# how do i count words in a message sent by a specific user using php?

Tags: php

it's a bit hard to explain, but hear me out.

i'm trying to make a simple site that counts the total amount of words a specific user sent based on a series of messages that was entered. it's like copy-pasting a whole bunch of messages from, let's say discord, to tally the total words each user have said. an example would be something like me copy-pasting this specific group of messages to be tallied:

> **user1 said:** i love pie
>
> **user2 said:** haha me too
>
> **user1 said:** high five bro!
>
> **user3 said:** i like pie too. let me join in
>
> **total words:** 17 words; user1 - 6 words; user2 - 3 words; user3 - 8 words

i'm hoping to use php for it because it's like the only thing i'm familiar with. i know there's str_word_count and preg_split and count for the word counting, but i don't know how i can make it so the site would know to count words for each user.

Comment: You want to do this on historical messages, or as messages get sent/received

Comment: Where are you going to keep the results

Comment: on historical messages. it's just copy-pasting messages on a textbox to tally the words each user sent. also, the results would likely be stored in a variable to be displayed. the example i put in the original post is just to give an idea on what i was going on about.